# Prediction for Kernel Density in R is much faster than Python

Tags: python, r, performance, kernel-density

I am looking to compute the 2D KDE of some large dataset on Python.
Whereas fitting the KDE performs well both in R (using `ks` package) and Python (whatever the package), evaluating the density for some new random large dataset is instantaneous in R, but takes a long in Python.

Is there anything I'm missing ? How can I speed up things in Python without parallelizing calculations ? Is there a significant difference in the way R and Python algorithms are coded ?

You will find below a reproducible example in R.

```
library(ks)
library(MASS)

data <- mvrnorm(1e5, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(10, 3, 3, 2), nrow = 2))
kn <- kde(data, H = diag(2))

new_data <- mvrnorm(1e5, mu = c(1, 5), Sigma = matrix(c(20, 6, 6, 4), nrow = 2))

a <- Sys.time()
kn_pred <- predict(kn, x = new_data)
b <- Sys.time()

b-a #Time difference of 0.005482912 secs
```

And now the same example in Python.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = [0,0], cov = [[10, 3], [3, 2]], size = 100000)
kn = gaussian_kde([data[:,0], data[:,1]], bw_method = 1)

new_data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean = [1,5], cov = [[20, 6], [6, 4]], size = 100000)

a = time.time()
kn_pred = kn([new_data[:,0], new_data[:,1]])
b = time.time()

print(b-a) # 131.60702800750732
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check if the inputs are the same (in size, content), then check which line takes the most time, then look into it's documentation to see if there are different default parameters that cause the difference in behavior.

Comment: Thanks @DannyVarod.
I double checked the gaussian_kde() documentation and its associated __call__() and evaluate() functions, and nothing seems to explain why evaluation takes much longer in Python.
The line taking the most time is between a and b in my Python reproducible example, and I don't know why, since all data have the same size. Did you have anything in mind ?

Comment: I haven't used this specific predictor, but I suspect that something like depth, number of iterations, condition for stopping or algorithm differ.